# ImportError: cannot import name 'WatermarkEncoder' from 'imWatermark'

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, watermark, stable-diffusion

I'm trying to run stable diffusion on my local pc. It's a macbook pro m1. Even though I did follow every single step, I keep getting an import error. What might possibly be the reason and how may I fix it?

ImportError: cannot import name 'WatermarkEncoder' from 'imWatermark'

I was referring an online tutorial so I did end up searching through the comments. Found nothing so far.

Comment: How, exactly, did you install the module you're trying to use?  There seem to be multiple modules out there with names similar to `imWatermark` - but the only one that seems to have a definition of `WatermarkEncoder` is actually named "invisible-watermark", and is used via `import imwatermark` (note lack of any capitalized letters).  I suspect you simply installed the wrong module.

Comment: "_Even though I did follow every single step ..._" Please describe which steps you took, and what the results were. What is `imWatermark`? Is it a module from PyPI (that you installed using `pip`)? If so, could you add a link to it? If it's your own code, could you include it in your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the txt2img.py script it references https://github.com/ShieldMnt/invisible-watermark

Install with `pip install invisible-watermark`

Answer (score 0):

It seems they forgot to add it into requirements.txt or smt like that.
If you continue getting the error after invisible-watermark installation, change the line `from imWatermark import WatermarkEncoder` in txt2img.py to `from imwatermark import WatermarkEncoder` (lowercase)